# This connection is using {tls_version} which is now

Tags: python

Using mysql.connector:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/Users/murlimohan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "/Users/murlimohan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 450
    f"This connection is using {tls_version} which is now "
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's at `db.py` line 6? It looks like the raw string `his connection is using {tls_version} which is now ` was used in a connection string or query. Did you try to construct either based on user input or data retrieved from another system? Did you use dynamic SQL with unescaped string input? The solution to that is to use parameterized queries instead of dynamic SQL

Comment: hostname = 'localhost'
username = 'root'
password = 'root'
database = 'v5_app'
print( "Using mysql.connector:" )
import mysql.connector
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect( 
    host=hostname, 
    user=username, 
    passwd=password, 
    db=database, 
    tls_versions=["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"], 
    unix_socket='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
)
myConnection.close()
print( "Using mysql.connector:" )

Comment: Add the code to the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem! I cannot `import mysql.connector` on Ubuntu 20.04 using python2.7. There is no more code to add to this example.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python2, aren't you? Because the version of `mysql.connector` you have is not compatible with that - it uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python), which Python2 cannot interpret. I'm facing the same problem and am now looking into installing an older version of the module. According to the [Oracle website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html), version 8.0.24 should work.